# What policy have bigger priority DMARC or SPF?

Tags: spf, dkim, dmarc

Lets provide hypothethical situation:

We have configured two records:

1. spf ~all which mean its softbounce and all mail which dont pass my spf goes to spam
2. v=DMARC1; p=none; sp=none;

So which policy have bigger priority. Does this combo mean that even if someone will try to phish my domain and will fail spf policy I allow to receive all this emails and show them in inboxex like normal email that pass spf record?

Answer (score 0):

When using DMARC there are two phases. First your server checks SPF and DKIM status, then it checks the results of those against your DMARC config to find out what it should do. If you set SPF to `-all`, it aborts this process early since it's an explicit `fail` which will cause it to skip DMARC processing - the correct approach is to set `~all` and let your DMARC record say what to do with it (e.g. reject).